# Set value inside table from database using array

Tags: android, mysql, json, android-volley

I am trying to fetch data from MySQL database and trying to show it into a table. For this I am using volley.

```
JSONArray result = response.getJSONArray("result");
                for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = result.getJSONObject(i);

                    String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                    String phone = jsonObject.getString("phone");
                    String email = jsonObject.getString("email");

                    String j = String.valueOf(i);

                    data = new String[][]{{j, name, email, phone}};

                    tableView.setDataAdapter(new SimpleTableDataAdapter(getActivity(), data));
                }
```

My json array

```
{
"result": [
    {
        "sl": "36",
        "user_id": "575512",
        "email": "m@gmail.com",
        "password": "123",
        "name": "Moderator",
        "gender": "Male",
        "phone": "1223345",
        "lvl": "Moderator",
        "stat": "1"
    },
    {
        "sl": "68",
        "user_id": "814769",
        "email": "m2@gmail.com",
        "password": "1WCcvnhp",
        "name": "Test Moderator",
        "gender": "Male",
        "phone": "7412589630",
        "lvl": "Moderator",
        "stat": "1"
    }
]
}
```

The problem is I am getting only the last value from jsonArray, because the String array is resetting itself.

```
data = new String[][]{{j, name, email, phone}};
```

**I want to get all the values available in the jsonArray.**

I am using the following dependencies for table

```
de.codecrafters.tableview:tableview:2.8.0
```

Comment: Just to clarify - do you want more that the last value from jsonArray? What is it that you do want from the program?

Comment: yes, I want all the values available in the jsonArray. @AJD

Comment: Edit the question so that it is clear to other helpers what you would like to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
JSONArray result = response.getJSONArray("result");
            for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = result.getJSONObject(i);

                String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                String phone = jsonObject.getString("phone");
                String email = jsonObject.getString("email");

                String j = String.valueOf(i);

                data = new String[][]{{j, name, email, phone}};
            }

                tableView.setDataAdapter(new SimpleTableDataAdapter(getActivity(), data));
```

After getting all values in array, add that array to tableview

Comment: Tried it just now, same thing, getting only the last value.

Comment: Here in that for loop  it is replacing value in each value of "i" .

Comment: Even if I don't use the i , only name, email, phone same problem. I tried it.

Comment: Create a bean class and add value to a List<BeanClass> and try to add to tableview

Comment: I did try the above mentioned method using BeanClass. Previously only the last was showing only 1 time, but now the same last last value showing multiple time.

Comment: What is the length of result array?

Comment: Try to debug and find the values in each loop positions